# Determine how many paragraphs fit on a Flowdocument

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

I am creating a `Flowdocument` with several `Paragraphs` dynamically, in order te take advantage of the `Paragraph`'s `KeepTogether` property. In this way the paragraphs will never be split across two pages when printing.

The paragraphs will have different size between two printjobs, but within a single print job they will always have the same size. I want to take advantage of this by adjusting the numbering of the paragraphs so that the first paragraph on each page will be consecutive to the number of the first paragraph on the previous page.

To be able to do this I need to know how many paragraphs will fit on one page. How can I do this?

Comment: That depends on the printer and page size. If you want tight control then why not use a FixedDocument.

Comment: How would a FixedDocument help me then? I tried that first, but printing stopped after the first page.

Comment: If your FlowDocument height can be determined, you can look at the LineHeight of each Block within a Paragraph and add them up to determine if any number of paragraphs will fit, no?